# Spring Boot app on Heroku save in database characters č , ć like ? ? . How to set encoding on Heroku for this letters?

Tags: spring, heroku, encoding

In spring boot application deployed to Heroku  when saving something in database , characters like Č and Ć are saved in database like ? . When run app localy everything is ok , using same database . Tried with .locale and buildpack but problem again exist

Comment: Are you using characters in your data that are non-alpha numeric?

Comment: No , data contains only non-alpha numeric characters and everything if fine when connect to database on heroku with app started on localhost . When deploy app on heroku and start it there  , this problem appears